# Docusign ESignature for Salesforce - how to add a radio button to a template?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am struggling to get the value of a Salesforce picklist to merge into a DocuSign document as a Radio Button Group.

I don't require the signer to be able to select a value in the radio button; it just needs to populate from the picklist property on the Opportunity.

I've unsuccessfully followed these instructions and am beginning to think they don't fit my use case: https://www.forcetalks.com/salesforce-topic/docusign-salesforce-integration-how-to-associate-a-picklist-on-salesforce-with-a-radio-button-on-docusign-template/

The result is the correct radio button is never selected (no option is selected).

I've searched and searched and only come up with results that seem to based on the instructions in that link.

I would think that I could add a custom tag but I've tried that and not been able to make that work.

Any help, links to docs, etc would be appreciated b/c I've come up short on my searching. Thanks!

Edit: I'm using the web interface and merge fields.
Edit 2: The tag says docusignapi but there is no docusign tag by itself and I don't have the rep to create it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select the radio button by setting the `selected` parameter to true. See the methods portion of the API reference under `RadioGroupTab.Radio` for more information https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/radiogrouptab.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not using the api. I'm using the web interface and merge fields. I'll update the question to make that clear.